# Can I name a turtle after a variable in python 3?

Tags: python, python-turtle

I want to use code like so:

```
import turtle as trtl
turtle = ["One", "Two", "Three"]
for each in turtle:
   each = trtl.Turtle()
```

I don't want three turtles named "each", I want each iteration of the for loop to use the variable each, but not the string "each". Is this possible?

Comment: there is no string "each"

Comment: Canonical: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/3001761

Comment: try using while True instead  i dont really know that you trying to do so I guessed this it might help idl

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve but `import turtle as trtl` is harmful to readability. Nobody knows what `trtl` is on a glance but everyone knows `turtle`, so I'd avoid introducing layers of pointless indirection like this. Name your variables around the library, not the other way around. If you want a list of turtles, use `turtles = [turtle.Turtle() for _ in range(3)]` and index them with `turtles[0]`, `turtles[1]`, etc which is the correct way to operate with sequential data instead of `"One"`, `"Two"`, etc.

Comment: @PaulH I guess I meant the word each instead of the variable

Comment: @Shad0w because I want to use the variable each and iterate through the list

Comment: @ggorlen I'm not sure what you're saying. I know about the turtle as trtl, I apologize, but I'm not understanding how proper indexing and that will work for what I'm trying to do, nor do I understand what ```turtles = [turtle.Turtle() for _ in range(3)]``` does

Comment: @JoshuaCuevas are you looking for only if you can naming of the variable or code if you are searching for code i can tell you your code wont work like this try this might help ```import turtle as trtl
turtle = ["One", "Two", "Three"]
turtle_dict = dict()
for each in turtle:
    turtle_dict[each] = trtl.Turtle()``` like this you can access your turtle by calling its name and the dict variable .

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do, but as others (and myself) are suggesting, very likely you want to use 1 and a list instead of "One" and a dict (or global, which is effectively a dict). The code I gave you is a list comprehension, but it's the same thing as making a list and then putting the items in using `append` one by one. I recommend reading answers in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/3001761) very carefully.